# How to write socket.io tests in JMeter?

Tags: sockets, socket.io, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

There is my simple server written with socket.io library:

```
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
});

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);
const port = 3000;

app.get('/help', (req, res) => {
  res.send('HELP PAGE')
})

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(socket.id);
  console.log('User connected');

  socket.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log('Message: ' + msg);
    io.emit('message', msg + socket.id);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('User disconnected');
  });
});

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server Socket.IO listen on: ${port}`);
});
```

I need to write test in JMeter. I use plugin from Peter for testing WebSockets. How should I write test for method `message`?

```
socket.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log('Message: ' + msg);
    io.emit('message', msg + socket.id);
  });
```

Could someone post his own test? I have already working tests in Postman, but there are special type of request for socket.io - unfortunately Postman is not such scalable as JMeter and I can't use it.

Answer (score 1):

Capture all the requests which are being sent by Postman using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and configure JMeter to send the same requests.

1. Add a [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to instantiate the initial HTTP connection and get `sid`

   [image]
2. Add a [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor) to extract the `sid` from the response

   [image]
3. Open a websocket connection

   [image]
4. Do what you need with this connection

   [image]

Comment: You helped me, but not definitive. All of my requests are green in Jmeter, but still server doesn't register "connection" function from Jmeter (log info is not fired). Status is 200