# WebSocket request is not catched when send via JMeter

Tags: websocket, socket.io, jmeter

I have server code written with SocketIO ([How to write socket.io tests in JMeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76659091/how-to-write-socket-io-tests-in-jmeter)).
I have also test in Postman and Jmeter.
Test from Postman works fine, and server properly writes all messages on console, writes that someone's connected or disconnected etc.
Unfortunately my JMeter tests indicated on well established connection, sending request (with code "200") which is displayed as "Green" but server doesn't register connection nor sent message.
I am pasting screenshots from Postman and Jmeter.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and compare the requests originating from JMeter and Postman.

The requests must be exactly the same (apart from dynamic values which need to be [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter))

Once you start sending the same messages with JMeter as Postman does you will be getting the same responses.

There is [socket.io-chatserversample.jmx](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/samples/socket.io-chatserversample.jmx) example test plan you can use as a reference

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I spend few hours on tuning this tutorial but with no results. Even line ```  console.log(socket.id);
  console.log('User connected');
``` doesn't fire. Ofc all requests are green